# Capybara .find().text but exclude item link text

Tags: css, ruby, capybara

Using Capybara, I am trying to get the text contained in a  however, I want to exclude all the text from the links in the TD.

**HTML**

```
<td style="height: 20px" class="title" width="50%">
        <a class="PSS" onclick="imgclick(0); return false;" href="">
        <img src="http://www.domain.com/pic.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a><br>
           First Line <br>
           Second Line
           Third Line <br>
        <a class="click_link" onclick="dataclick(0);" href="">View field</a>
</td>
```

**Code**

```
 .all('#Table > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr').each do |tr|
     tr.find('td:nth-child(1)').text
 end
```

I am trying to do something like..

```
 .all('#Table > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr').each do |tr|
     tr.find('td:nth-child(1)').exclude('a').text
 end
```

However, there is no exclude method.

I am trying to get:   First Line Second Line Third Line

I do not want: First Line Second Line Third Line View field

Comment: what about something like: find('selector').all('other selector').select{|elm| elm.tag_name != 'a'}.first.text